# What happens exactly when a python class instance use dot to access attributes?

Tags: python, python-class, python-attrs, python-magic

Suppose a class `A` is defined as:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

After `A` is instantiated by `a = A(3)`, what methods will be called by executing `a.val`? In other words, what will happen internally when `a.val` is executed?

Moreover, how about `A` accessing a non-existed attribute, namely `other_val`, by executing  `A.other_val`?

I heard about built-in methods such as `getattr` and `setattr`, and class protocol method `__getattr__`, `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__`, which of them and how they are triggered when `A.*` is executed?

I only found few documentations on this, so any materials that explains the problem will help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which documentation have you found so far?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names gives a pretty good overview of what each of these special methods does

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Thanks for your link and I even failed to find this official documentation. This official document looks quite useful to my problems and I will delve into it. Feedbacks will be commented later.

Answer (score 1):

When you [try to] access a class instance attribute using dot notation, the class's __getattribute__ method will be invoked. This can be demonstrated thus:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 99
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        print(f'Acquiring {attr}')
        return super(type(self), self).__getattribute__(attr)


a = A()

print(a.val)
```

**Output:**

```
Acquiring val
99
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it helps. I wanna go deeper into the invoking process. Does `A.*` immediately invoke `__getattribute__` or immediately invoke some other methods that further invoke `__getattribute__`?